# Can't start glassfish server. Start failed

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-4.1

Recently I can't start glassfish server on Netbeans(I use glassfish 4.1).

I've tried to remove server and add it again. It worked for a while but after I restarted my computer it produced a same error.

Below is the error output.

```
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   Shutdown requested
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has a query component
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:427)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:243)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:326)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:374)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:392)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Severe:   Startup service failed to start
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has a query component
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:427)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:243)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:326)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:374)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:392)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 935ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=admin-listener, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 7ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
Info:   Server shutdown initiated
Severe:   Shutdown required
MultiException stack 1 of 1
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has a query component
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:427)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:243)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:326)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:374)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:392)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Info:   Server shutdown initiated
Info:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@7b3315a5 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@29ea78b1.
Info:   Unregistered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@7b3315a5 from service registry.
Info:   FileMonitoring shutdown
Warning:   Exception while unregistering: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service already unregistered.
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl.unregister(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:123)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl.unregisterService(EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl.java:93)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl.stop(EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl.java:81)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.StopServer.doExecute(StopServer.java:78)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.StopDomainCommand.execute(StopDomainCommand.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at org.glassfish.api.AsyncImpl$1$1.run(AsyncImpl.java:76)

Completed shutdown of Log manager service
Info:   Shutdown procedure finished
```

Comment: Does your application contain any files with a question mark (`?`) in their name?

Comment: Do you mean my project in Netbeans? If so, the answer is no.